# any way to disable mouse gesture in microsoft mouse for Linux?

Tags: mouse, gestures

Beginning to migrate to natural keyboard, I bought a wireless keyboard/mouse from Microsoft, and am quite happy with it. I can live with the "Windows" button on the mouse. But every time I (accidentally) move the mouse in a certain way, my web browser moves back a step in history - and that´s on Windows *and* Linux.
Does anybody know a way to disable that?

Even if I could open the device, which I can´t because I can see no screws (When I just opened it to see if I could find any screws, I noticed that it also has a "forward" gesture) , I would not know what wire to cut (literally speaking). And I can find no setting in Windows Mouse Settings to disable it.

-- update

Microsoft´s "Mouse and Keyboard Center" let me disable the gesture on Windows. Did not deactivate the force feedback, but ok.

However, the gesture is still active when I plug it into Linux. (Btw it´s not moving the mouse, it´s hitting the Windows Button in a certain way that triggers the gesture.)

Comment: You surely won't be able to solve it altering the hardware, gestures don't have dedicated hardware (wires etc) neither to detect them neither to send to the pc. The only way to disable it is through software, but I can't tell more without knowing more details on your issue.

Comment: I get a force feedback from the mouse when I activate the gesture. I guess that that cannot come from the OS but must be built in.
It´s the Sculpt Comfort Desktop by the way.

Comment: Maybe this should migrate to AskUbuntu?

Comment: I'd also like to be able to disable it on linux, or at least make it less sensitive. By the way, it's caused by swiping the blue button up or down.

Answer (score 1):

I just ripped that button right off--problem solved. Instead of ripping the ribbon cable, some say you can unplug the sensor without disassembly (https://www.windows10forums.com/threads/aggravating-vibration-creates-involuntary-action.12885/) though there is usually a ZIF clip you can unclip with this type of connector if you disassemble. The button under the touch sensor still works. If you don't like the way it looks you can snap it back in after you cut the cable (or disassemble the mouse and unplug the cable to make the change reversible). Even if disconnected, you will need that touch panel or a shim just as thick to be able to press the button easily, if you even want that button.

If you don't like the button for the Start Menu, you could remove the underlying white block that presses it, then add color-matched black wood putty to keep the blue exterior in place (or to take its place entirely).

Years later, M$ has locked all issues on their Answers site about this yet hasn't provided a configuration screen. I don't know who would want this garbage feature, especially when there is no way to turn it off! I lost form data this way and so did other people on their Answers site. I have a Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse. Swipe up is forward and swipe down is back. It is clearly easy to do accidentally when you are merely adjusting your grip.

Comment: N1! I was annoyed by the battery consumption of the set at some time, so I switched to a wired solution: I use a Periboard and some bargain mouse now. A little loud, but but the most ergonomic solution I ever had, apart from the somewhat bulky keys.